# Integrating ui.qml files into existing ui application

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator, qt-designer

I've created a small application. The GUI is ugly, I've done it quickly. I've created a ui.qml file with Qt Design Studio.

My question is : is it simple to use my ui.qml file instead of my ui file ? I mean, do I have to change all my code when I call ui->ComponentName ?

I tried to understand how ui.qml files works, but it seems it's a completely different way to use component in C++ files than ui files..

Comment: I have to say that after written many Qt applications I never use Qt Design Studio. The idea behind Qt Design Studio is for big teams, you may have a separation between the Developer Team and the UI/UX Team. That's where you would use ui.qml files since it helps with this separation. If you are a single developer, then, the benefits of using this approach diminishes. Especially, if you are new to Qt QML, it's probably better that you start of with something more elementary.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. I have a lack of imagination to design things. I liked the fact we can click on buttons and test some things to customs components in Qt Design Studio. It's harder to do the same only by customizing with stylesheets. I'll assume I have to deal with stylesheets :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the build system you are using, files ending with .ui are used by autouic to generate C++ code that you can call to create your user interface, usually from the constructor of your class that will be the parent for those components.

This is done by calling `setupUi` on the member variable 'ui', which is the same class name as the parent class, just under the `Ui` namespace.

QML code is interpreted, however, and can be read by `QQmlApplicationEngine`. You can expose properties with `setContextProperty`, taking a `QString` and a `QObject*`, as explained further here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html#exposing-methods-including-qt-slots